# Why does MySQL/MariaDB consider a string (uuid) equal to integer?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table (mariadb:10.3):

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `public_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `old_slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `people_uuid_unique` (`uuid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `people_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `people_public_id_unique` (`public_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When I run the below query against this table, I am getting the below result. For some reason the first number inside the string is matching against the ID which is an auto incrementing integer.

Query:

```
select * from `people` where `id` = "1f028a28-f032-482b-a8b4-dc5483489552"
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | public_id   | uuid                                 | name        | slug                    | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 8ipui1pn9ln | 52ea30f4-cafa-4ddb-8b74-1502a34c3c21 | Mark Hamill | 8ipui1pn9ln-mark-hamill | 2020-04-15 18:47:33 | 2020-04-15 18:47:35 |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Just a note, this is slimmed down example. The real reason I am searching a string against an integer is because I am searching a dynamic value against multiple columns with and `OR`.

Comment: Note that a slimmed down version might use an id like '3c21' instead of '52ea30f4-cafa-4ddb-8b74-1502a34c3c21', for ease of comprehension.

Comment: Surely, "name" cannot be `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will implicitly try to cast a string to an int by taking the first sequence of digits and ignoring anything from the first letter onwards.

Not an intuitive behavior, but once you're aware of it, you can avoid it by explicitly casting such conditions to strings.

Comment: That clears it up. Thank you. After doing some more reading, I was able to utilize the `BINARY` function on my where statement to get the result I am looking for.